# Is $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ for entries in commutative ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, determinant

It is well known (and the proof is simple) that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ when $A,B\in M_n(F)$ where $F$ field. But what about for $A,B\in M_n(R)$ where R is any arb. commutative ring?

A field is distinguished from a com. ring by the presence of multiplicative inverses. I feel like this isn't a necessary condition for proving the determinant function is a homomorphism but I'm having a hell of a time trying to do so.

How would I go about proving the above?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Matrix_Product has it for matrices over a commutative ring.

Comment: What is the proof you know ? (the answer is yes, by the way, but I'm not sure what "simple" proof doesn't work in general)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi the proof I know involves decomposing either matrix A or matrix B into a product of elementary matrices. Then we can rely on a lemma (which is true for matrices with entries in com. ring, not necessarily fields) whereby det(AE)= det(A)det(E) for elementary matrix E. If $B=E_1E_2...E_k$ then det(AB)=det(A)det(B) pops out immediately as a result. But writing an arbitrary matrix B with entries in com. ring as a product of elementary matrices is proving harder than I thought.

Comment: @William Right, so, that's actually the proof I was considering. But how do we know that an invertible matrix with entries in com. ring can be written as a product of elementary matrices?

Comment: The formula $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ (for $n \times n$ matrices with any particular $n$) is an identity of polynomials over $\mathbb Z$ in the entries of $A$ and $B$, and therefore is true in any commutative ring.

Comment: See my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2443302/uniqueness-of-characteristic-polynomial-of-linear-transformation-in-finite-field/2443345#2443345

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof based on the abstract definition of the determinant:

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is an $R$-module. Define $\bigwedge^n M$ to be the quotient of $M^{\otimes_R n}$ by the sub-$R$-module generated by the pure tensors $x_1\otimes ... \otimes x_n$ such that there exist $i\neq j$ with $x_i = x_j$. The image of the pure tensor $x_1\otimes ... \otimes x_n$ in this quotient is usually written as $x_1\wedge ... \wedge x_n$.

Note that by expanding out $(x+y)\otimes (y+x)$, it follows that in this quotient we have relations analogous to $x\wedge y = - y\wedge x$, and more generally, $x_{\sigma(1)}\wedge ... \wedge x_{\sigma(n)} = \epsilon(\sigma) x_1\wedge ... \wedge x_n$, where $\epsilon(\sigma)$ is the signature of the permutation $\sigma$.

Then

> Lemma 1: If $M=R^n$ is free of rank $n$, $\bigwedge^k R^n$ is free of rank $\binom{n}{k}$, a basis being given by the $e_{i_1}\wedge ... \wedge e_{i_k}, i_1 <...< i_k$ (the $e_i$'s being the canonical basis of $R^n$)

It's fairly straightforward to prove that they generate $\bigwedge^k R^n$, slightly more complicated to show that they are linearly independent, but they are.

In particular, with $k=n$, $\bigwedge^n R^n$ is free of rank $1$. In this case, one possible way to show that $e_1\wedge ... \wedge e_n$ is not zero is to show that $\det : (R^n)^n \to R$ actually factors through $(R^n)^n \to\bigwedge^n R^n$ (that's because $\det$ is $n$-linear and satisfies the condition that if two of the rows of the matrix are equal, then $\det = 0$) and has value $1$ on $(e_1,...,e_n)$. This is the only case we will need, so this is a possible proof if you already know what $\det$ is.

Note that this proof actually shows more : it shows that $\det : \bigwedge^n R^n\to R$ is an isomorphism.

> Lemma 2: Any $R$-linear map $f:M\to N$ induces an $R$-linear map $\bigwedge^n f: \bigwedge^n M\to \bigwedge^n N$ given by $x_1\wedge ... \wedge x_n \mapsto f(x_1)\wedge ... \wedge f(x_n)$. In particular, $\bigwedge^n (f\circ g) = \bigwedge^nf \circ \bigwedge^n g$

This is the key point, and is not hard to show.

> Proposition 1: Let $f: R^n\to R^n$ be an $R$-linear map. Then $\bigwedge^n f$ is an $R$-linear endomorphism of a free $R$-module of rank $1$, so it's a homotethy. The homotethy in question is given by $\det(f)$.

Proof: we showed that $\det : \bigwedge^n R^n \to R$ was an isomorphism of $R$-modules, with inverse given by $1\mapsto e_1\wedge ... \wedge e_n$. Therefore it suffices to show that $\det\circ \bigwedge^n f(e_1\wedge...\wedge e_n) = \det(f)$. But that's clear, because $\bigwedge^nf(e_1\wedge...\wedge e_n) = f(e_1)\wedge ...\wedge f(e_n)$ by definition, and $\det(f)$ is by definition $\det(f(e_1),...,f(e_n))$.

Note : this might seem a bit circular to people who *define* the determinant by this proposition. Here I'm assuming that the OP knows what the determinant is, and proving, based on that, that it's equivalent to this.

> Corollary (Conclusion) : $\det(f\circ g) =\det(f)\det(g)$.

Proof: By Proposition 1, $\bigwedge^n (f\circ g)$ is given by multiplication by $\det(f\circ g)$. But by lemma 2, $\bigwedge^n (f\circ g) =\bigwedge^n f\circ \bigwedge^n g$ is given by the composition of multiplication by $\det(f)$, and the multiplication by $\det(g)$, so multiplication by $\det(f)\det(g)$. Therefore, because it is over a free module, $\det(f\circ g) = \det(f)\det(g)$.

Let me make another note: it seems like we did no hard work at all. This is only what it looks like, the hard work is in the definition of the determinant, essentially in showing that $\bigwedge^n R^n$ is in fact free of rank $1$. The proof I gave here was that we had an explicit isomorphism, given by the determinant, this presupposes we know that the determinant exists, is $n$-linear, and satisfies the condition on matrices with two equal rows.